# Objective C removeObjectsAtIndexes desire cleaner coding

Tags: ios, objective-c

I would like to create a shorter and more elegant version of some working code.

FYI I have to add an element to an existing array, and then remove one, and repeat. (unfortunately I can't add more than one element and then remove more than one).

Working code:

```
NSMutableArray *destinationArray;
destinationArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *originArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

// Copy one specific array element from originArray to destinationArray
// Note: assume originArray and destinationArray populated at this point
int originIndex = var1-var2+1;
[destinationArray addObject:originArray[originIndex]];

// Remove one specific array element from destinationArray
[destinationIndex removeAllIndexes];   // clear index if used previously
[destinationIndex addIndex:var3-var4-1];
[destinationArray removeObjectsAtIndexes:destinationIndex];
```

I would prefer some version of the following:

```
[destinationArray addObject:originArray[var1-var2+1]];
[destinationArray removeObjectsAtIndexes:[var3-var4-1]];
```

Is there a way to make this shorter version work? (gives expected identifier error)

Thanks much for your help...

Comment: Your implementation is different from what you asking. You code won't work and it will get crash because you did not added any object in `originArray` and you are trying get object from empty array.

Comment: @Bhumeshwerkatre Read the comments in the code.

Comment: Why are people down voting this question? The question is clear, it shows relevant code, and it shows some effort. What else do people want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not do this:

```
NSMutableArray *destinationArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *originArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

// somewhere in here objects are added to "originArray"

[destinationArray addObject:originArray[var1-var2+1]];
[destinationArray removeObjectAtIndex:var3-var4-1];
```

Comment: What is var1,var2, var3,var4 here?

Comment: @Bhumeshwerkatre Ask the OP.

Comment: Well done maddy, thank you, works great.  As someone new to Objective C I just had some extra brackets messing things up.  And Bhumeshwerkatre: the vars are just integers used to set the right index value.